# How do I use local::lib with fish shell?

Tags: perl, shell, fish

I'm still quite new to fish shell but this is really important for making me want to stay using it.

If I try and activate local::lib with a normal bash style command:

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
```

I get:

```
$(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(perl)'.
fish: eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `$` and double quotes in `"$()"`,

```
eval (perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get:

```~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 1): Unsupported use of '='. In fish, please use 'set PATH "/Users/user1/perl5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"'.```

Comment: @JonLorusso This suggests you're using a combination of fish and bash (or some other POSIX shell). For instance, if your default shell is fish, but you've specified bash as your shell within vim, then you may see this error when running shell commands through vim as the perl expression isn't smart enough to handle this case. In this case, you can use `set -x PERL_MB_OPT "--install_base \"/home/user/perl5\""` and `set -x PERL_MM_OPT "INSTALL_BASE=/home/user/perl5"` (with correct paths) explicitly in your config.fish (which is what the perl expression evaluates to when run from fish).